# Delphi DX10.4 E2064 code does not compile

Tags: delphi

I'm not much of a Delphi programmer, I'm happy to do C++Builder programming, delphi is not my language.  I have some components written in Delphi and they compile fine in 10.3 but I do get errors in 10.4, and I can see the problem why, but I have no clue how to fix it. Please help me fix it.

```
procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte; Src, Dest, Trans, Extra: pChar)

    Dest^ := Char(fOwner.GammaTable[pByte(Longint(Src) + 2)^]); inc(Dest);  // changed these two, but I have no clue what I'm doing lul
    Dest^ := Char(fOwner.GammaTable[pByte(Longint(Src) + 1)^]); inc(Dest);
    Byte(Dest^) := fOwner.GammaTable[pByte(Longint(Src)    )^]; inc(Dest);  // ERROR here
```

The way I see here, as I understand in C++, there is a byte being initialized, and it is being assigned. Similar to char('a') = 5; But I can see what the code originally wants to do, assign something to address of Dest.

How should I change this stuff around so it works??

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what error you received. However, `Dest` is a `PChar`, so `Dest^` is a `Char`. This is a two-byte value, so you cannot cast it to `Byte`.

Comment: Unless you deal with 16/48bit RGB all those variables just want to deal with bytes, not words. Use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar` - your function name indicates 8bit anyway.

Comment: This code looks defective anyway, even if you can get it to compile. `Char` is two bytes wide in both versions you refer to. As well as getting the code to compile, you'll likely want to get it to work!

Comment: @AmigoJack OP is manipulating RGB byte data.  They should not use `Char` or `PAnsiChar` - those are string types for characters and text.  `Byte` and `TBytes` would be suitable.  There is no sensible solution with `pChar` as an argument, so fundamentally this method can never be useful.  How to design a replacement for it will depend on the context you're working in.  Selecting a suitable argument type should be the first step.

Comment: @J... this looks like code working fine with i.e. Delphi 7 which now needs adjustments for being used in X10.4, yet nobody is helping at that.

Comment: @AmigoJack The question isn't about that though. This site isn't about bespoke individual support, it's about building a repository of widely useful topics.

Comment: @AmigoJack "Fixing" legacy code by making the same mistakes again 18 years later should not be our aim.  The data is not character or text data - `char` types don't belong.

Comment: One thing you *could* tell us is the type of `fOwner.GammaTable`.  Overall, in any case, I think the strategy with this method should be to rewrite it completely getting rid of `PChar`, `Char`, and using `Byte` and `PByte`, or better, getting rid of ugly pointer arithmetic altogether and using `TBytes`.  How you end up refactoring this, though, will depend entirely on the constraints of the rest of this application - constraints we can't see and cannot include in our advice.

Comment: PChar type was "abused" in the past as it allowed for pointer arithmatic if I remember correctly and was byte sized at the time (pre-unicode). So perhaps you can change (P)Char to (P)Byte and use PointerMath directive http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirspointermath_xml.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the declaration of `GammaTable`. I created one which seems suitable. I have not initialized it here, but it should be in your code. If your declaration is different, maybe my code has to be modified.

```
var
    GammaTable : array [Byte] of Byte;

procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8(const Pass: Byte; Src, Dest, Trans, Extra: pChar);
var
    BDest : PByte;
begin
    BDest  := PByte(Dest);
    BDest^ := GammaTable[PByte(UIntPtr(Src) + 2)^]; Inc(BDest);
    BDest^ := GammaTable[PByte(UIntPtr(Src) + 1)^]; Inc(BDest);
    BDest^ := GammaTable[PByte(UIntPtr(Src)    )^]; Inc(BDest);
end;
```

I have not changed the arguments type on the function, but for sure `Src` and `Dst` should be `PByte` not `PChar`. Anyway, the code I wrote will work equally well whatever it is provided it contain the desired source and destination table.

I introduced the `BDest` variable to make the code more readable.

Note that if `Src` is declared as `PByte` and `{$POINTERMATH ON}` then the code can be simplified:

`PByte(UIntPtr(Src) + 2)^`

becomes

`Src[2];`

So the procedure can be rewritten like this:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
procedure CopyInterlacedRGB8_(const Pass: Byte; Src, Dest : PByte; Trans, Extra: pChar);
begin
    Dest[0] := GammaTable[Src[2]];
    Dest[1] := GammaTable[Src[1]];
    Dest[2] := GammaTable[Src[0]];
end;
```

Much more readable, isn't it?

Comment: `PByte` is declared with `{$POINTERMATH ON}` already enabled on it, so you don't need to manually enable pointer math in your own code to use pointer math on a `PByte` variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good to know!

Comment: I'd probably just dump the unnecessary `Trans` and `Extra` parameters - at least for this example they are totally pointless.  OP hasn't shown us any code that requires them.